# How do you reverse shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, setuptools, distutils

Good morning to everyone i am kind of new to python and wanted to get into more advanced coding. So basally i would like to fix a friend or family computer without physical being there. I end up doing my research and stumble across reverse shell from this website (https://github.com/buckyroberts/Turtle/blob/master/Multiple_Clients/setup.py). When i try to open the terminal in pycharm and type in setup.py build i get this error

`line 23, in <module>
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Freeze'`

So i assumed `cx_Freeze` was outdated so i replace `cx_Freeze` to `from setuptools import setup` so i end up  getting another error `executables=[Executable("client.py", base=base)])`. Can this error be fixed?

Comment: `cx_Freeze` and `setuptools` are two different things (though they both contain a setup function).

Comment: you have to install [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) to run this code.

Comment: How and where do I install cx_freeze

Comment: @outkast, installation commandline on https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/ (A common way to install modules for Python, incidentally.)